# Which companions play a substantive role in the Legacy DLC?

Tags: dragon-age-2

*Dragon Age II: Legacy* allows you to choose whomever you want for your party makeup, but there seems to be a few choices that provide more flavor than others.

For example, Varric has a ton of cutscene dialogue (at least early on) and one of the achievements/trophies for the DLC requires Bethany/Carver to be in your party when you complete all the quests.

On the other hand, Merrill doesn't seem to have any cutscene dialogue (again, at least early on), and just acts as a bit player, not even acknowledging a prior relationship.

Do any of the other companions play more of a role in the DLC? Or are the only two important characters *per se* Varric and Bethany/Carver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anders has a good bit of dialogue, and some cutscenes/answers to questions as well as a semi-large part near the end.

Isabela also has some dialogue with Varric, but not any cutscenes of her own.

Answer (score 1):

Fenris also has quite a lot of good dialog. Nothing hugely long, but he typically has quite a different and interesting perspective on things. Also some unique dialog with the Arishok due to his history with the Qunari.

I skipped using him on my first playthrough as I was also a two-handed warrior, but he was definitely worthwhile having in the party on the second playthrough as a blood mage.